# How java matches Exception?

Tags: java, exception

```
public class ExceptionDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            int x = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

            System.out.printf("try: x = %d\n", x);

            int z = 42 / x;

            System.out.printf("try: z = %d\n", z);

            return;

        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            System.out.println("ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: " + e.getMessage());

        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("NumberFormatException: " + e.getMessage());

        } catch (ArithmeticException e) {
            System.out.println("ArithmeticException: " + e.getMessage());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception: " + e.getMessage());

        } finally {
            System.out.println("finally");
        }

        System.out.println("end");
    }
}
```

When I try input 0,java catches "ArithmeticException".
The question is how java knows ArithmeticException is ArithmeticException?
So I look for ArithmeticException class.

```
public class ArithmeticException extends RuntimeException {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2256477558314496007L;

    /**
     * Constructs an {@code ArithmeticException} with no detail
     * message.
     */
    public ArithmeticException() {
        super();
    }

    /**
     * Constructs an {@code ArithmeticException} with the specified
     * detail message.
     *
     * @param   s   the detail message.
     */
    public ArithmeticException(String s) {
        super(s);
    }
}
```

There is no special in ArithmeticException class.
How the java detect the error "42/0" is the ArithmeticException?
Just because ArithmeticException extends RuntimeException?

Comment: Dividing by zero (for integer division) throws an `ArithmeticException`, that's [defined](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.6) in the Java Language Specification. What do you mean by "how java knows ArithmeticException is ArithmeticException"? It's hard to understand what your question is.

Comment: at the end of the day, some code needs to know to throw a certain type of exception, in this case if the divisor is 0, it says, OK Freen lets throw a `ArithmeticException`

Comment: *There is no special in ArithmeticException class.* **Wrong** `public class ArithmeticException extends RuntimeException`

Comment: Java does not detect that "42/0" is an `ArithmeticException`, rather it detects that "42/0" is not a good thing to do and it creates a new  `ArithmeticException` and throws it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your question is, how does Java know that it should throw an `ArithmeticException` when you try to divide by 0?

Because the language specification says so:

> JLS Section 15.17.2
>
> ...On the other hand, if the value of the divisor in an integer division is 0, then an ArithmeticException is thrown.

That's *it*. Because it says so, it does so.

I can't explain this any further because we can't know the implementations of operators like `/` unless we look at the source code of the Java compiler. If it's a method, we can just read the source code of the JDK.

Answer (score 0):

The way `try/catch` work is as following (taken from [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catch.html))

> The catch block contains code that is executed if and when the
>   exception handler is invoked. The runtime system invokes the exception
>   handler when the handler is the first one in the call stack whose
>   ExceptionType matches the type of the exception thrown. The system
>   considers it a match if the thrown object can legally be assigned to
>   the exception handler's argument.

So basically when an exception is thrown, the code will walk through all of your catch statement to see if any of the catch clause matches the exception ("match" = "can be assigned to the exception handler's argument"). If there's a match, the corresponding exception handler will be invoke. If there's none, the exception will be bubbled up to the caller.

Another way to look at this is if you have your code like this:

```
try {
    // 42/ 0
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Got Exception");
} catch (ArithmeticException e) {
    System.out.println("ArithmeticException: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

Then you'll see that it will always print "Got Exception" and not the "ArithmeticException ..."